# Jquery - if condition true, loop through selector and do something

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get this piece of code to work:

HTML:

```
<div class="content-block blog-post clearfix zoomIn animated" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
<div class="content-block blog-post clearfix zoomIn animated" style="position: absolute; left: 451px; top: 0px;">
<div class="content-block blog-post clearfix zoomIn animated" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 466px;">
<div class="content-block blog-post clearfix zoomIn animated" style="position: absolute; left: 451px; top: 476px;">
```

Jquery:

```
var a = $(".category-susans-personal-blog .archive_page .wpb_thumbnails .blog-post").css("position") == "absolute" && $(".category-susans-personal-blog .archive_page .wpb_thumbnails .blog-post").css("left") == "0px";
var b = true;
var c = a && b;

    $(".category-susans-personal-blog .archive_page .wpb_thumbnails .blog-post").each(function(i, obj) {
    if(c){
        $(this).addClass("left");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("right");
    }
});
```

What I'm trying to do is: if `.blog-post` has `position:absolute;left:0`, add the class `.left` else `.right`.

Below is the html output of the current javascript:

```
<div class="content-block blog-post clearfix zoomIn animated left" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
<div class="content-block blog-post clearfix zoomIn animated left" style="position: absolute; left: 451px; top: 0px;">
```

Thanks!

Comment: 1. Javascript variables doesn't start with `$` That's PHP. But it's not disallowed either. It this case though it's probably not correct since starting a variable with **$** usually denotes a jquery object which those variables are not. (They are boolean). 2. `var c = a && b` where **&&** is the logical *and-operator*.

Comment: ok, changed that, but it' still not working, I will update the code here too

Comment: `var c = a && b;`. not `c = $a && $b;`. also `var b = true;`. Not using `var` makes the variable *global*.

Comment: Actually I need to edit the question, but thanks for the support so far, I'm on the right path I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding two true/false doesn't give you true or false, it gives you a number:

```
True + true = 2
True + false = 1
False + false = 0
```

Also, you will need to move the first line inside the each():

```
    $(".category-susans-personal-blog .archive_page .wpb_thumbnails .blog-post").each(function(i, obj) {
var $a = $(this).css("position") == "absolute" && $(this).css("left") == "0px";
    if($a){
        $(this).addClass("right");
        } else {
        $(this).addClass("left");
    }
    });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r247yy98/)

Comment: yea, this seems to work on the fiddle, but not on my site.I don't know why it's not working for me, maybe some other thing is causing the problem.Thanks so much for all of your time and help guys, I do appreciate it.

Comment: Maybe switching the classes? Right now, you are adding 'right' if left position is 0. Seems like it should be the opposite.

Comment: yea, I know.I missplaced the classes when I typed the code, but the problem is that only one class is applyed to both divs, and it's the `.left` class

Comment: Is there anywhere else you are modifying the divs? Are there any other styles the divs have applied to them?

Comment: yea, there is a lot of css on this theme.But I checked, and there are no classes overriding each other or things like that.That's why I wanted to add new classes

Comment: I'll wait untill tommorrow to see if I can find a fix for it,if it was something else that was causing the problem, I will mark your answer as the good one, since you were the first one who fixed my code.Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot "add" booleans together this way:

```
$c = $a + $b;
```

All you're doing is coercing both to integers. Since `$b` is *always* true, you're going to be doing either `$c = 0 + 1` or `$c = 1 + 1`, but either way the result is that `$c` will be a *truthy* value.

You need to use boolean logic operators such as `&&` or `||`. If you want to say "both a AND b must be true", you need `&&`:

```
$c = $a && $b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Still not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish but this might be a nudge in the right direction (if you want just the divs with `position: absolute` and `left: 0px` to get the `right` class):

```
$(".category-susans-personal-blog .archive_page .wpb_thumbnails .blog-post").each(function(i, obj) {
  var a = $(this).css("position") === "absolute" && $(this).css("left") === "0px";
  var b = true;
  var c = a && b;

  if(c) {
    $(this).addClass("right");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("left");
  }
});
```

Which can be simpliefied to:

```
$(".category-susans-personal-blog .archive_page .wpb_thumbnails .blog-post").each(function(i, obj) {
  if($(this).css("position") === "absolute" && $(this).css("left") === "0px") {
    $(this).addClass("right");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("left");
  }
});
```

**Update**

After your edit you state that you just want `.blog-post` which have `position: absolute` and `left: 0px` to have the `left` class added to them.

Then something like this should be more sufficient:

```
$(".blog-post").each(function(i, obj) {
  if($(this).css("position") === "absolute" && $(this).css("left") === "0px") {
    $(this).addClass("left");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("right");
  }
});
```

Comment: not exactly, because I want this to apply to `.blog-post`, but only on one category, which is represented by this class `.category-susans-personal-blog`